# VB.NET 2005 - Cannot Bind To New Display Member - ComboBox - Array

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

all,

I am using a stored proc to obtain records from an SQL Server 2005 database using an INNER JOIN. I am using VB.NET 2005. I am passing a parameter to the stored proc and then loading the results into a list of string, then populating the ComboBox with that list of string.

The error I am getting is:

> Argument Exception System.ArgumentException Complex DataBinding
>   accepts as a data source either of IList or an IListSource. at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value) at
>   NotaryTrackIT.GlobalStuff.PopulateDropDownList2(ComboBox&ControlName,
>   String TheState, Boolean AutoComplete) in
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\NotaryTrackIT\NotaryTrackIT\NotaryTrackIT\Modules\GlobalStuff.vb:line
>   182.

This is the scenario. I have a ComboBox that is being populated with US state codes from a database. This works perfectly fine. When the cursor moves out of this ComboBox, another ComboBox is supposed to populate a list of the counties within that particular US state. However, when the cursor moves out of the ComboBox, the error is generated, but, the US counties ComboBox does have values, which makes no sense. I am not sure why the error is being generated.

This is my code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStateCounties
(
    @TheState AS CHAR(2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT S.StateID AS SPK,
           S.StateAbbrev AS SA,
           SC.StateID AS SFK,
           SC.CountyName AS CN
    FROM States AS S
    INNER JOIN StatesCounties AS SC
    ON S.StateID = SC.StateID
    WHERE S.StateAbbrev = @TheState
    ORDER BY CN
END
```

The VB code to populate the ComboBox is (Function):

```
Public Function PopulateCounties(ByVal TheState As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim LoadCounties As New List(Of String)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Using SetDatabaseConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectToDatabase)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            Try
                With cmd
                    .CommandText = "GetStateCounties"
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .Connection = SetDatabaseConnection
                    .Parameters.Add("@TheState", SqlDbType.Char).Value = TheState
                End With

                With SetDatabaseConnection
                    If .State = ConnectionState.Broken _
                    OrElse .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                        .Open()
                    End If
                End With

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                While dr.Read
                    LoadCounties.Add(dr("CN"))
                End While
            Catch RangeEx As IndexOutOfRangeException
                MessageBox.Show(RangeEx.ToString(), _
                                "Index Out Of Range Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch CastEx As InvalidCastException
                MessageBox.Show(CastEx.ToString(), _
                                "Invalid Cast Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch ArgNullEx As ArgumentNullException
                MessageBox.Show(ArgNullEx.ToString(), _
                                "Argument Null Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch ArgEx As ArgumentException
                MessageBox.Show(ArgEx.ToString(), _
                                "Argument Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch SQLEx As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show(SQLEx.ToString(), _
                                "SQL Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch InvalidOpEx As InvalidOperationException
                MessageBox.Show(InvalidOpEx.ToString(), _
                                "Invalid Operation Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch NotSuppEx As NotSupportedException
                MessageBox.Show(NotSuppEx.ToString(), _
                                "Not Supported Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Catch NullRefEx As NullReferenceException
                MessageBox.Show(NullRefEx.ToString(), _
                                "Null Reference Exception", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Finally
                With SetDatabaseConnection
                    If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        .Close()
                    End If
                End With
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    Return LoadCounties
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles State.LostFocus, AddressType.LostFocus, PhoneNumberType.LostFocus, EmailAddressType.LostFocus
    Try
        With CType(sender, ComboBox)
            .BackColor = Color.White
            .ForeColor = Color.Black

            If .Name.Equals("State") Then
                Dim TheCountiesToAdd = PopulateCounties(State.Text.ToString.Trim)

                For Each TheCounties As String In TheCountiesToAdd
                    With CType(Territory, ComboBox)
                        .Items.Clear()
                        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
                        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
                        .DataSource = TheCountiesToAdd
                        .DisplayMember = "CN"
                        .ValueMember = "CN"
                    End With
                Next TheCounties
            End If
        End With
    Catch CastEx As InvalidCastException
        MessageBox.Show(CastEx.ToString(), _
                        "Invalid Cast Exception", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    Catch OutOfMemEx As OutOfMemoryException
        MessageBox.Show(OutOfMemEx.ToString(), _
                        "Out Of Memory Exception", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    Catch ArgEx As ArgumentException
        MessageBox.Show(ArgEx.ToString(), _
                        "Argument Exception", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error, _
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The code for `PopulateDropdownList2` is not given, but that's the actual exception site.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
For Each TheCounties As String In TheCountiesToAdd                
    With CType(Territory, ComboBox)
        .Items.Clear()
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .DataSource = TheCountiesToAdd
        .DisplayMember = "CN"
        .ValueMember = "CN"
    End With
Next TheCounties
```

by:

```
With CType(Territory, ComboBox)
     .Items.Clear()
     .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
     .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
     .DataSource = ConvertToDataTable(TheCountiesToAdd)
     .DisplayMember = "CN"
     .ValueMember = "CN"
End With
```

Here the Function:

```
Public Function ConvertToDataTable(Of T)(ByVal list As IList(Of T)) As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add("CN")
    For Each item As T In list
        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        row("CN") = item
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return table
End Function
```